# useFetch custom hook + Debounce React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Objective: create a reusable useFecth custom hook + debounce component so that the API does not get call after every keystroke instead once the user is done typing
[example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-api-call-l05yc?file=/src/App.js:1009-1127)

What I have:

1. input tag that will trigger the debounce function
2. after the debounce function gets executed it will set a new value and trigger useFetch custom hook
3. custom hook gets executed and makes an API Call

The Problem:
if the value, which is a dog breed, is typed wrong or provide a value (dog breed) that does not exist it will throw an error that I'm handling in my useFetch hook. so far so good, the problem is that if I want to pass another value (dog breed)  that exists it still throw the does not exist error when it should not. It feels like it gets stuck there and it does not re-renders.

```js
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import IsLoadingComponent from "./isLoadingComponent";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [dogBreed, setDogBreed] = useState("");

  //custom fetch hook
  //will be trigger after debounce function is done executing
  const url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dogBreed}/images/random`;

  const { data: randomImage, isLoading, hasError, errorMessage } = useFetch(
    url,
    dogBreed
  );

  //debounce the value after user is done typing not after every keystroke
  const debouncedSave = useCallback(
    debounce((nextDogBreed) => setDogBreed(nextDogBreed), 500),
    [] // will be created only once initially
  );

  //this will trigger the debounce function
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value: nextDogBreed } = e.target;
    setValue(nextDogBreed);

    debouncedSave(nextDogBreed);
  };

  // console.log(dogBreed);
  // console.log(randomImage);
  // console.log(hasError);
  // console.log(errorMessage);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder="breed" onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      {isLoading ? (
        <IsLoadingComponent />
      ) : hasError ? (
        <h1>{errorMessage.message}</h1>
      ) : (
        <img
          src={randomImage}
          alt="dogImage"
          style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", marginTop: "2rem" }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**useFetch custom Hook**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url, dogBreed) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dogBreed) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const result = await response.json();
          if (response.ok) {
            setData(result.message);
          } else {
            setHasError(true);
            setErrorMessage(result);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          setHasError(true);
          setErrorMessage(err.message);
        } finally {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    } else {
      setData("https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/african/n02116738_10215.jpg ");
    }
  }, [url, dogBreed]);
  return { data, isLoading, hasError, errorMessage };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: My gut feeling is that hasError isn't being reset correctly. Can you try explicitly setting it to face after if (dogBreed) in the hook?

Comment: Your question is unclear... How you test that your hook works? What one needs to write? and as mentioned, onError you don't reset `setData`

Comment: Im not sure what you guys mean by onError dont reset setData? 
the hook works well up till I added the handling errors. if I enter a correct value it will return a random pic of the dog breed, if i enter a value (dog breed) that does not exist it will return an error message (that's what i want), but if i enter a valid value again it still return an error message when it should return a random pic of the dog breed entered.

Comment: I added a link to my codesandbox, I'm not sure if that is of much help?

Comment: Can't replicate it @JCastillo. I tested on CodeSandbox and it seemed to work. First entered "f", got invalid breed. Then entered "labrador", and it returned a labrador. Using Chrome on Windows 10, for reference.

Comment: @Gorbles I found the bug, I only had to set the hasError back to false. But I appreciate you looking into it

Answer (score 1):

Custom fetch with caching and debouncing.

```
    const debounce = (fn: any, time: any) => {
    let timer: any;
    return (...args: any) => {
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(()=> {
            timer = null
            fn(args)
        }, time)
    }
}
const useFetch = (num: string) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const cache = useRef<Map<string, {}>>(new Map())



    useEffect(() => {
        async function call() {
            if(cache.current.has(num)){
                const d = cache.current.get(num) as {}
                setData(d)
            }else{
                try{
                    setLoading(true)
                    const r = await axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${num}`)
                    setData(r.data)
                    cache.current.set(num, r.data)
                }catch(err){
                    setError('Request failed')
                    setData({})
                }finally{
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            }
            
        }
        if(num.length){
            call()
        }else{
            setData({})
            setLoading(false)
        }
    },[num])

    return [data, error, loading]
}   


const Component = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [resp, setData] = useState({})
    const [debouncedTerm, setDebouncedTerm] = useState('')
    const [data, error, loading] = useFetch(debouncedTerm);


    const cb = useCallback(debounce((v: string) => setApiCallVal(v), 1000),[])

    const changeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValue(e.target.value)
        cb(e.target.value)
    }    



    if(loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return (
        <section className="container">
            <section className="header-wrapper">
                <h1>Fetch + Debounce</h1>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} value={value} />
                <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
                {error}
            </section>
        </section>
    )
}
```